# Array concatenation discrepancy

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I am learning JavaScript via FREECODECAMP.

---

Here is what I am asked to do:

> Compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both. In other words, return the symmetric difference of the two arrays.
>
> Note
> You can return the array with its elements in any order.

---

Here is what I did, it works, and passes the tests:

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  let newArr = [].concat(arr1.filter(item => {
    return !arr2.some(item2 => item2 == item);
  })).concat(arr2.filter(item => {
    return !arr1.some(item2 => item2 == item);
  }));
  return newArr;
}

console.log(diffArray(
  ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"],
  ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]
));
```

I also tried this and it also works:

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  let newArr = [].concat(arr1.filter(item => {
    return !arr2.some(item2 => item2 == item);
  }));
  let newArr2 = [].concat(arr2.filter(item => {
    return !arr1.some(item2 => item2 == item);
  }));
  return newArr.concat(newArr2);
}

console.log(diffArray(
  ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"],
  ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]
));
```

---

Buuuuuut... My question is... Why this last solution does not work?:

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  let newArr = [].concat(arr1.filter(item => {
    return !arr2.some(item2 => item2 == item);
  }));
  newArr.concat(arr2.filter(item => {
    return !arr1.some(item2 => item2 == item);
  }));
  return newArr;
}

console.log(diffArray(
  ["andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"],
  ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]
));
```

Comment: The problem is that `a.concat(b)` doesn't *change* `a` - it produces new array. You have the code `newArr.concat(arr2.filter(item => { return !arr1.some(item2 => item2 == item); }));` which is the same construct. It works if you capture the new array in a variable or if you directly return it (like in the second code block).

Comment: Totally makes sens now, thank you !